# Нужна ли здесь запятая? [2]

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста: нужна ли здесь запятая?

**"Каникулы прошли и мне стало грустно".**

Здесь вроде бы лишь одна грамматическая основа (**каникулы прошли**); я бы запятую не поставил. Но, может, я чего-то не знаю...

Comment: Здесь две грамматические основы (стало грустно - второе сказуемое, без подлежащего). Насчет запятой не знаю. По идее здесь причинно-следственная связь, поэтому безбоязненно можно воткнуть запятую. Хотя вроде бы есть и обратные примеры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычное сложносочиненное предложение, вторая часть которого является односоставным, безличным предложением. Запятая  после "прошли" должна стоять.

Comment: Большое спасибо!